# Is it possible to use Lpad in side Rpad or vice versa

Tags: oracle

I'm new to Oracle Functions

Here I'm trying to generate output like this

Sample :- `****OUR NAME****`

How to frame `LPAD`,`RPAD` in a query to make the above Sample output

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You can do something like below. See a [Demo Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7/3696)

```
SELECT RPAD(LPAD('OUR NAME',12,'*'),16,'*') FROM DUAL;
```

You can use the `LENGTH()` function as well like

```
SELECT RPAD(LPAD('OUR NAME',LENGTH('OUR NAME')+4,'*'),LENGTH('OUR NAME')+4+4,'*') FROM DUAL;

SELECT RPAD(LPAD('GOOGLE',LENGTH('GOOGLE')+4,'*'),LENGTH('GOOGLE')+4+4,'*') FROM DUAL;
```

See here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7/3703

Comment: For your answer if i put GOOGLE in place of OUR NAME the output is like ******GOOGLE**** .. How to use Length function so that I can get equal number of stars like 2 or 3 stars(*) to left and right side of google

Comment: In this case you are actually adding equal no.of starts by calculating the length of the string to pad to. see the filldle demo link in answer.